# yii in submit button display confirm message two time

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2, yii-components

In my form, I have given a confirmation message before saving.

```
CHtml::submitButton('Save', array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to save?'));
```

But the message box appears two times... What is wrong ?

Comment: u can use afterValidate method for that ...... for forms

Comment: the best way to use the event onsubmit of form ... not click of submit button... so there is a method afterValidate and beforeValidate and otheres there so u can call ur javascript confirmation there.... if u use client validation.... it needs client validation set to true..

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::button('Admit',array('submit' => array('/student/admissionStudentDetails/admit_Confirm', 'id'=>$model->admission_id),'class'=>'submit','confirm'=>'Are you sure admit this student?')); ?>

Comment: please give idea how to pass value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the form where you can got the answer of your thing... this is one way of doing it...!!!

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                  'id'=>'customer-form-guest',
                                  'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                                  'clientOptions'=>array(
                                  'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                                  'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) { 

                                                      if(hasError) {

                                                               alert("There are errors in form inputs please resolve it.");

                                                          }
                                                          else
                                                          {


                                                            var r = confirm("Are you sure y7ou want to do this ..?");


                                                           if(r == true)
                                                           {
                                                              return true;
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                             return false;
                                                            }



                                                          }
                                                     }' ),
                                   'htmlOptions'=>array('role'=>"form")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
    array('confirm'=> 'Are you sure?')); ?>
```

When Click on Save then Same Page render than Controller generate view that time also who messege that's an issue. You have to pass some value in URL and then When view load that time just write condition for that does't show twice.

Comment: <?php echo CHtml::button('Admit',array('submit' => array('/student/admissionStudentDetails/admit_Confirm', 'id'=>$model->admission_id),'class'=>'submit','confirm'=>'Are you sure admit this student?')); ?>

Comment: please give idea how to pass value.